# Web Design: Transparent image rotating and zoom in/out

Tags: javascript, css, animation

https://jacekjeznach.com/skills/
In this link, he has a transparent image of different words in it. And it's revolving and can be zoomed in/out. I was wondering what is it called and how can I do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `<canvas>` element, animated using javascript.

From a quick look in the source code it looks like some implementation of [this repo](https://github.com/goat1000/TagCanvas).

You can find the repository documentation [here](https://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas.php).

Here is the source from the site you linked:

```
if( ! $('#myCanvas').tagcanvas({
    textColour : '#a5a5a5',
    outlineThickness : 0.5,
    outlineColour : '#FE0853',
    maxSpeed : 0.06,
    freezeActive:true,
    shuffleTags:true,
    shape:'sphere',
    zoom:0.8,
    noSelect:true,
    textFont:null,
    pinchZoom:true,
    freezeDecel:true,
    fadeIn:3000,
    initial: [0.3,-0.1],
    depth : 1.1
})) {
// TagCanvas failed to load
$('#myCanvasContainer').hide();
```